# how to develop custom alert box in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I want an alert box having input fields and login button,as for authentication.

I require this on my first page of site so please help in this.

alert("in this area");

Comment: Please first try to create something. If you get stuck, then ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved using Angular Bootstrap,

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

You can check the Modal section of the site (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).

Create a Bootstrap modal containing your input fields and login buttons, and write the code to open it on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Here its explained good, please have a look into this https://www.npmjs.com/package/lg-custom-alert.

```
<button lg-alert="[scope-function]" lg-size="[size of the modal]" lg-type="[type]" lg-message="[message need to be displayed in the alert">
    Alert 
</button>
```

Comment: While it is OK for an answer to contain links for reference, the answer itself should at least contain a basic explanation.